# Is this procedure valid for finding the limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

$$\begin{align*} \lim_{x\to \pi/4} (1-\tan x )^{\cos x -\sin x } 
&= \lim_{x\to \pi/4} \frac{(1-\tan x )^{\cos x}}{(1-\tan x )^{\sin x }} \\
&= \lim_{x \to \pi/4} \frac{\ln (1-\tan x )^{\cos x } }{\ln (1-\tan x )^{\sin x }} \\
&= \lim_{x\to \pi/4} \frac{\cos x }{\sin x } \\
&= \lim_{x\to \pi/4} \cot x \\
&= \cot \frac{\pi}{4} \\
&= 1 \end{align*}$$

I didn't want to use L'Hopital so I tried this. I think I divided by 0. Help please (:

Comment: What's the justification of second step to third step?

Comment: and for what reason do you want to avoid L'Hopital?

Comment: Your edit of the title of the question now makes the entire question unclear in its intent.  You need to be **precise** and unambiguous about what you are asking; moreover, you should not ask a question, read the responses to that question, and then go back and edit your original question to ask some other question, since this invalidates all of the answers that you had previously received and causes confusion for other readers.

Comment: I hate LHR too. In this case I would rather exponentialise it as $\exp((\cos x-\sin x)\ln(1-\tan x))$ and apply Taylor series, which in general is much slicker than LHR.

Comment: Dividing by zero is acceptable if you are taking limits and you aren't dividing by zero on the points that are the limit.  But taking the logs of both terms of a fraction doesn't yield an equality.  I.e x/y $\ne $ ln x/ln y.  So how does your third step work?  The forth step wold work though.

Comment: You [asked about deleting your account](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1773658/7). See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9456/delete-my-account) for instructions about this. (But think a bit about it before you make the decision. I can say from my own experience that this website can be very useful.)

Answer (score 4):

The taking of logarithms in the numerator and denominator has no logical basis.  Doing such a thing is like saying $$\frac{2}{3} = \frac{\log 2}{\log 3},$$ which of course is absurd.  Consequently, your calculation from that point forward is incorrect.

The other problem with the question is that the function $$f(x) = (1 - \tan x)^{\cos x - \sin x}$$ is not in general real-valued for $\pi/4 < x < \pi/2$, since in this interval, $1 - \tan x < 0$.  Hence the two-sided limit, strictly speaking, does not exist.  The one-sided limit (from below) does, however, which we show as follows:

Note that $$1 - \tan x = \frac{\cos x - \sin x}{\cos x}.$$  So $$f(x) = (g(x) \sec x)^{g(x)} = g(x)^{g(x)} (\sec x)^{g(x)},$$ where $g(x) = \cos x - \sin x$.  As $x \to \pi/4^-$, $g(x) \to 0^+$ whereas $\sec x \to \sqrt{2}$, hence the limit of the second factor exists and equals $1$, allowing us to write $$\lim_{x \to \pi/4^-} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \pi/4^-} g(x)^{g(x)} \cdot \lim_{x \to \pi/4^-} (\sec x)^{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to \pi/4^-} g(x)^{g(x)}.$$  Then we merely conclude that the remaining limit can be regarded as a function of $g$ rather than $x$, i.e., $$\lim_{x \to \pi/4^-} g(x)^{g(x)} = \lim_{g \to 0^+} g^g = 1.$$

Comment: Thanks, I do know that the step is absurd, the normal equation to use would be x = e^(ln x). But why does this work? Is it a mere coincidence? It got me thinking if there are other limits like this one.

Comment: Your question is a bit like asking, "if we can get the right answer of $1/4$ by canceling the digit $6$ in the numerator and denominator of $16/64$, why does this work?  Is it coincidence?  For what other fractions does this work?"  An absurd step does not become legitimate simply because you happen to have obtained a correct result.

Comment: But if there are enough of those fractions, and we were able to find a pattern to predict when to use that absurd step, could it become a legitimate step? (just to find answers faster).

Comment: @heropup: The analogy with "$16/64$" is a great choice. (That said, ["Anomalous Cancellation"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnomalousCancellation.html) has been a topic of study, at least recreationally. So, asking "For what other fractions does this work?" isn't to be dismissed *entirely*. ;)

Comment: A common mistake (not applicable here)  made in applying l'Hopital's rule is that it is  valid when the limit exists, but there are examples where l'Hopital's rule gives you an "answer" for the limit when in fact , the limit does not exists. So to logically apply it,you must also prove that a limit exists.

Comment: FYI 98/49=8/4=2, by cancelling the 9's...:)

Comment: @user254665: That's (the reciprocal of) one of the examples given in MathWorld's ["Anomalous Cancellation" entry](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnomalousCancellation.html) that I mentioned above. :)

Comment: "Is it coincidence?"  Yes.  That's not such a hard concept is it?

Comment: @fleablood. On this site, this year,someone asked why $\arctan x$ was not equal to $(\arcsin x)/(\arccos x).$

Comment: I'm not saying it's not a legitimate mistake.  But if you recognize that it is a mistake, and ask why despite being a mistake in one circumstance it leads to a correct answer, wonder aloud if it might be a coincidence, all as the OP did, then you ought to be willing to accept the answer is ... "why, yes.  It *is* a coincidence"..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use L'Hopital you can use continuity.

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\pi/4}(1-\tan(x))^{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\pi/4}\ln\left((1-\tan(x))^{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}\right)\right)\\
=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\pi/4}(\cos(x)-\sin(x))\cdot\ln\left((1-\tan(x))\right)\right)
\end{equation}

Now, write $$\ln\left((1-\tan(x))\right)=\ln\left(\frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\right)=\ln(\cos(x)-\sin(x))-\ln(\cos(x))$$

So we may calculate two distinct limits:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\pi/4}(\cos(x)-\sin(x))\cdot\ln\left(\cos(x)-\sin(x)\right)=\lim_{y\to0}y\cdot\ln(y)=\lim_{y\to0}\ln\left(y^y\right)\\
\lim_{x\to\pi/4}(\cos(x)-\sin(x))\cdot\ln\left(\cos(x)\right)=0
\end{equation}

Since $y^y\to 1$ as $y \to 0$ (from the positives), the first limit is $0$, to the original limit is $\exp(0)=1$.

Comment: I really like this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we have both base and exponent as variables it is best to take logs in order to evaluate the limit. Also note that the limit here must be as $x \to \pi/4^{-}$ so that $(1 - \tan x) > 0$. Thus if $L$ is the desired limit then we have
\begin{align}
\log L &= \log\left\{\lim_{x \to \pi/4^{-}}(1 - \tan x)^{\cos x - \sin x}\right\}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \pi/4^{-}}\log(1 - \tan x)^{\cos x - \sin x}\text{ (via continuity of log)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \pi/4^{-}}(\cos x - \sin x)\log(1 - \tan x)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \pi/4^{-}}(\cos x - \sin x)\{\log(\cos x - \sin x) - \log \cos x\}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \pi/4^{-}}(\cos x - \sin x)\log(\cos x - \sin x) - (\cos x - \sin x)\log \cos x\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \pi/4^{-}}(\cos x - \sin x)\log(\cos x - \sin x) - 0\cdot \log 1\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0^{+}}t\log t\text{ (putting }t = \cos x - \sin x)\notag\\
&= 0\notag
\end{align}
Hence $L = 1$. Here we have used the standard limit $$\lim_{t \to 0^{+}}t^{a}(\log t)^{b} = 0$$ for positive $a, b$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\lim_{x\to \pi/4} (1-\tan x )^{\cos x -\sin x }=\left[\lim_{x\to\pi/4}\left(1-\tan x\right)^{1-\tan x}\right]^{\lim_{x\to\pi/4}\cos x}$$

Set $1-\tan x=y$